# PHP - Redirect with id in json

Tags: php, json

I wrote a PHP code where I am parsing Ids with data from my JSON file.

My idea is to redirect a view of specific id as I need to write data for specific user id. (all json data of that user) based on a click.

In my user.php I have:

```
$projectRoot = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT');
$json = file_get_contents($projectRoot . '/assets/json/users.json');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data as $item) {

echo ("<tr><td><a href=\"main.php?id=".$item[0]['id']."\">Read user data</a></td></tr>");

}
```

and in my main.php I have:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = (int) $_GET["id"];
    $projectRoot = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT');
    $json = file_get_contents($projectRoot . '/assets/json/users.json');
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    $jsonfile = $data[$id];
}
?>

<ul>
 <li><?php echo $jsonfile["firstName"] ?></li>
 <li><?php echo $jsonfile["LastName"] ?></li>
</ul>
```

My user.php page randers me a numbers of users. When click on specific number need to trigger a main.php view of that specific user with its data.

First problem I have is that when I click on specific number it wont redirect to that view just reloading the same page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a `</tr>` in this line `echo ("<td><a href=\"main.php?id=".$item[0]['id']."\">Read user data</a></td></tr>");` but no `<tr>` Is that naffing up your HTML layout and causing the anchor tag to not work??

Comment: Also, without a sample of your .json file, I think this is wrong: `$item[0]['id']` ... shouldnt that be: `$item['id']` instead?

Comment: No, var_dumping it I get 1 2 3 4 5 ...@IncredibleHat

Comment: I aded that, but it ' s not something that is cousin and issue. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Hm. So... clicking a basic standard `a` anchor link on a plain web page, does not go to main.php at all? Do you have any javascript loaded up thats hijacking your anchors? I find it hard that a basic `a` will not... do something.

Comment: It's reloading the same page it seems but not redirecting? Is there something that I am missing? @IncredibleHat